# Extract data out of ORC using Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, orc

I have a ORC file i am able to read that into a DataFrame using Pyspark 2.2.0

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df = spark.read.orc("s3://leadid-sandbox/krish/lead_test/")
```

The above df has a schema like below

```
root
 |-- item: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

sample data looks like this(Just a sample data not the entire dataset)

```
item
{http_Accept-Language={"s":"en-US"}, Win64={"n":"1"}, 
geoip_region={"s":"FL"}, Platform={"s":"Win7"}, geoip_postal_code=
{"s":"33432"}, JavaApplets={"n":"1"}, http_Accept={"s":"*/*"}, 
Version={"s":"11.0"}, Cookies={"n":"1"}, Platform_Version=
{"s":"6.1"}, http_Content-Type={"s":"application/x-www-form-
urlencoded"}}
{http_Accept-Language={"s":"en-US"}, Win64={"n":"1"}, IFrames=
{"n":"1"}, geoip_region={"s":"CA"}, Platform={"s":"Win7"}, Parent=
{"s":"IE 11.0"}, http_Dnt={"n":"1"}}
```

So I exploded "item" like below

```
expDf = df.select(explode("item"))
```

The above DataFrame has below schema and when i do an show(2) has the below details

```
root
 |-- key: string (nullable = false)
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)

+------------+----------+
| key| value|
+------------+----------+
|geoip_region|
{
    "s": "FL"
}
|
| Tables|
{
   "n": "1"
}
|
+------------+----------+
```

How can i select data out of this DataFrame ? I have tried different ways but of no use.
So i would need 'geoip_region' with value as 'FL' and so on.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Joshi for your response, for some reason i was getting row[0] not found error on my code, I was running this on AWS Glue environment may be that could be a reason.

I got what i wanted using the below code.

```
# Creating a DataFrame of the raw file

df = spark.read.orc("s3://leadid-sandbox/krish/lead_test/")

# Creating a temp view called Leads for the above dataFrame
df.createOrReplaceTempView("leads")

# Extracting the data using normal SQL from the above created Temp 
  View
tblSel = spark.sql("SELECT get_json_object(item['token'], '$.s') as 
token, get_json_object(item['account_code'], '$.s') as account_code 
from leads").show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure your full use case, but if it just about having access to keys and value inside "item", you can do it using following sample code:

```
row = df.select(df.item).collect()
```

Above line will give you a list of `Row` Object like `[Row(item={http_Accept-Language={"s":"en-US"}, Win64={"n":"1"},....})]`

Then to select all the values inside the row you can do: `row_item = row[0]['item']`

`row_item['http_Accept']` will give you access to `u"{"s":"en-US"}"`

and `eval(row_item['http_Accept'])` will give you a dictionary from where you can get its key,value

I have just outlined the process, which can be written with loops to get all the key/values in iteration.

Comment: Hi Joshi thanks for looking into this and answering it, I am not little clear about how to map output key 'http_Accept' with value 'en-US'. I think thats what you are talking about on the   'eval(row_item['http_Accept'])' but i dint quite understand this part.

Comment: my bad, try this: row = df.select(df.item).collect() , lang_dict = eval(row[0]['item']['http_Accept-Language']), lang_dict['s']